# Azure SQL Authentication Active Directory Default Slow

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework-core, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database

We are transitioning from using usernames and passwords in Visual Studio to "Authentication=Active Directory Default" in our Azure SQL connection strings for EF Core.
We are experiencing startup times taking 3 times as long since this change as it appears the token acquisition is really delaying things, possibly down to attempting to authenticate different ways that are unavailable.

There appears to be ways to add settings to environmental variables to disable mechanisms other than Visual Studio as the method but I haven't gotten them to improve things.

Is anyone aware of a fix for this issue?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/e9cbf9b31df595b2b34268fa91e14be9d57bdfd3/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/src/Credentials/DefaultAzureCredentialOptions.cs#L213

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/ado-net/sql/azure-active-directory-authentication?view=sql-server-ver16#using-active-directory-default-authentication

https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/1473

****UPDATE****

In case it's of any use to anyone, I started to build out an interceptor. I haven't fully implemented this yet but in case it's helpful I'll leave it here.

You can register this as like this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors#registering-interceptors

```
public class AadAuthenticationInterceptor : DbConnectionInterceptor
    {
        public override InterceptionResult ConnectionOpening(
            DbConnection connection,
            ConnectionEventData eventData,
            InterceptionResult result)
            => throw new InvalidOperationException("Open connections asynchronously when using AAD authentication.");

        public override async ValueTask<InterceptionResult> ConnectionOpeningAsync(
            DbConnection connection,
            ConnectionEventData eventData,
            InterceptionResult result,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var sqlConnection = (SqlConnection)connection;

            var token = await GetAzureTokenCache();
            sqlConnection.AccessToken = token;
            return result;
        }


        public static async Task<string> GetAzureTokenCache()
        {
            AzureTokenItem tkn = new AzureTokenItem();
            
            var AppDataFolder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + "\\YourFolder\\";
            if (File.Exists(AppDataFolder + "AzureTokenCache.txt"))
            {
                var tokenText = File.ReadAllText(AppDataFolder + "AzureTokenCache.txt");
                var tmpTkn = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AzureTokenItem>(tokenText);
                if (tmpTkn.ExpiresOn > DateTime.Now)
                {
                    return tmpTkn.Token;
                }
            }

            var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions
            {
                // Disable the token credential that we don't use
                ExcludeEnvironmentCredential = true,
                ExcludeInteractiveBrowserCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzurePowerShellCredential = true,
                ExcludeSharedTokenCacheCredential = true,
                ExcludeVisualStudioCodeCredential = true,
                ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true,
                ExcludeAzureCliCredential = true,
            });

            
            var azureTkn = await tokenCredential.GetTokenAsync(new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/" }));

            tkn = new AzureTokenItem
            {
                ExpiresOn = azureTkn.ExpiresOn.LocalDateTime,
                Token = azureTkn.Token
            };

            Directory.CreateDirectory(AppDataFolder);
            File.WriteAllText(AppDataFolder + "AzureTokenCache.txt", JsonSerializer.Serialize(tkn));
            
            return tkn.Token;
        }
    }
    public class AzureTokenItem
    {
        public DateTime ExpiresOn { get; set; }
        public string Token { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Has anyone any ideas on this as it's taking over 20 seconds for our first requests to go through now?

Comment: You're caching the access token, in plain text, on disk. This makes me nervous because the point of AAD auth is to avoid developer secrets sitting on the machine. This is my motivation anyway. DefaultAzureCredential is also meant to refresh tokens, and here it looks like it's going to be forced to auth every time a token expires rather that simply refreshing. Which is ultimately quicker? Hard to tell tho without some proper testing.

Comment: Absolutely and this is obviously a decision to be made. I would hope most developers have some form of disk encryption enabled on their machines. This is the same way the user secrets operates, so if you're using that it's not necessarily an extra issue. In my experience the slowness comes from the first request so it would appear caching is done in memory.

Answer (score 4):

I feel you pain. I got it ok-ish by implementing a custom authentication provider and explicitly configuring the auth sources to use:

```
public class MySqlAuthenticationProvider : SqlAuthenticationProvider
{
    public override async Task<SqlAuthenticationToken> AcquireTokenAsync(SqlAuthenticationParameters parameters)
    {
        var context = new TokenRequestContext(new[] { "https://database.windows.net/" });
        var options = new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions() {
            ExcludeManagedIdentityCredential = true
            // Exclude more.. 
        };
        var token = await new DefaultAzureCredential(options)
            .GetTokenAsync(context, default);
        return new SqlAuthenticationToken(token.Token, token.ExpiresOn);
    }

    public override bool IsSupported(SqlAuthenticationMethod authenticationMethod)
        => authenticationMethod.Equals(SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryDefault);
}
```

You wire this up in program start-up by:

```
SqlAuthenticationProvider.SetProvider(
    SqlAuthenticationMethod.ActiveDirectoryDefault,
    new MySqlAuthenticationProvider()
);
```

This way I got initial connection speed on VS auth from ~15+ sec to ~6 sec.

This is still slow, but bearable, especially if warmed up asynchronously while other parts of app start up.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've actually just updated my original post with the Interceptor I built out. I haven't fully tested it or anything yet but the concept is sound. I added file system based caching for the token to persist restarts which you could probably do too.