# How to use Active Directory Default and tell it to use Visual Studio?

Tags: authentication, azure-sql-database, connection-string

In order to connect to our Azure SQL Database locally when debugging in Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code, we set `Authentication=Active Directory Default` in the SQL Connection String.

This causes a tiny bit of slowness, and a lot of extra noise in the logs as it unsuccessfully attempts to connect 3 different ways that will never work before getting to the way we actually want to connect.

I prefer this over MFA authentication so that no UI is required to login, but I'm not aware of a way to connect via Visual Studio/Code without using `Active Directory Default`.

Is there a way to use `Active Directory Default` and specify which of the ways you actually want to connect rather than it having to go through each of them, or is there another way to effectively accomplish the same thing?

Answer (score 1):

If Azure default authentication is slow, you can make use of a custom authentication provider and explicitly configure the auth sources. Use the connection string below:

```json
"Server=tcp:<servername>.database.windows.net,1433; Database=<databasename>;" }
```

Access the token for the database using the code below:

```js
var connectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("<connectionstringname>");
            services.AddTransient(a =>{
                var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
                var token = credential
                        .GetToken(new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
                            new[] { "https://database.windows.net/.default" }));
                sqlConnection.AccessToken = token.Token;
                return sqlConnection;
```

For more information, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76513896/azure-sql-authentication-active-directory-default-slow).